# How do I read certificate information automatically using OpenSSL

Tags: apache-2.4, openssl, ubuntu-14.04

To generate an SSL certificate file for [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server), I am using the below command:

```
 openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.cert
```

And I manually feed it with these parameters:

> Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:**AU**
>   State or Province Name (full name): **Myname**
>   [Some-State]:**Some-State**
>   Locality Name (eg, city) []:**City**
>   Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:**Internet**
>   Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:**Section**
>   Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:**yourname**
>   Email Address []:**email@gmail.com**

Is it possible to enter them from a file or right from an OpenSSL command line using options?

There is no hint from the OpenSSL man pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a configuration file and use that in your command. You could for example create a config file named `openssl.cnf` and use it like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.cert -config ./openssl.cnf
```

In your case you can set the following parameters:

```
[ req_distinguished_name ]
# Variable name             Prompt string
#-------------------------    ----------------------------------
0.organizationName          = Organization Name (company)
organizationalUnitName          = Organizational Unit Name (department, division)
emailAddress                = Email Address
emailAddress_max            = 40
localityName                = Locality Name (city, district)
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
countryName             = Country Name (2 letter code)
countryName_min             = 2
countryName_max             = 2
commonName              = Common Name (hostname, IP, or your name)
commonName_max              = 64
```

More can be found at http://www.flatmtn.com/article/setting-openssl-create-certificates#SSLCert-4

Comment: This only sets the default values and the prompt text.  The OP wants to avoid using the prompting completely.

Comment: `-batch` Non-interactive mode

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere in your config file you need the following:

```
[ req ]
prompt                 = no
distinguished_name     = req_distinguished_name

[ req_distinguished_name ]
countryName             = GB
stateOrProvinceName     = Provinceshire
localityName            = Locationsville
organizationName        = Example Ltd
organizationalUnitName  = PKI
commonName              = www.example.com
```

The `prompt = no` in the `[ req ]` section stops the prompts you see and changes the format expected in the `distinguished_name` section.  If you don't have this option, OpenSSL will expect the prompting format that you currently have.

Note that the order of the fields are changeable and dictate the order in the certificate.

Answer (score 4):

It could also be run from a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

country=WORLD   
state=mystate    
locality=Mycity   
organization=myorg    
organizationalunit=IT   
email=email@gmail.com

 openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout
 /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.cert -subj
 "/C=$country/ST=$state/L=$locality/O=$organization/OU=$organizationalunit/CN=$commonname/emailAddress=$email"
```

Found it at: http://www.jamescoyle.net/how-to/1073-bash-script-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-key-and-request-csr